# Fastest way to find a subset of strings in another string?

Tags: java, string, complexity-theory, huffman-code

I am decoding a byte file made by huffman encoding, i turn the bytes into string and then search the values i have been given by the huffman tree. I have a hash table with the encode value and the byte value of the original file. Here is my code.

```
for(int i = 0, j = 1; j <= encodedString.length(); j++){

        if(huffEncodeTable.get( encodedString.substring(i, j)) != null){

            decodedString.append(huffEncodeTable.get( encodedString.substring(i, j)));
            i = j;      

        }
```

Its pretty simple, its a loop that itterates over all the string, the problem comes when the string its too large, -with compress files of size larger that 100KB- its takes a really long time to process them, so i want to know if its a way to make this process in a faster way or if its better to store my encode values in another structure intead of the hastable.

huffEncodeTable -> hashtable

encodedString -> String with the huffman values

decodedString -> The String that will represent the original bytes of the original file

Comment: I would compare your results to the built in huffman encoding (though most of the code is implemented using native code)  The built in compression also uses arithmetic encoding which can make the data smaller again.  The standard compression has a limit of how far back it will search e.g. 4 KB. this make encoding the look back easier as well.

Comment: I  have used just huffman, it really compress well som types of files, but what i dont see is where this loop takes really long time, so im asking what should i change here.

Comment: The built in huffman encoding can support multi-GB files without taking increasingly longer, so if it is doing this I suspect you have a bug (if only a performance bug) Additional arithmetic compressing can make it 2 to 10x smaller again.

Comment: Yeah i know i`m doing something wrong, and the problem is in the method i share up here, so i dont know if someone could tell me what is taking that much time in this instructions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

Every time you append to a String, a new String is created.  You should use `StringBuilder` instead.  This is probably the main problem, as I see it.

Also, I'd use `hashtable.containsKey` instead of `get` to check for a key's existence.  I doubt it impacts your performance much though.

You also might save a bit of time if you store the results of the call to substring, and so only call it once.

So, something like.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
String currentString;
for(int i = 0, j = 1; j <= encodedString.length(); j++){
    currentString = encodedString.substring(i, j)
    if(huffEncodeTable.containsKey( currentString )){

        sb.append(huffEncodeTable.get( currentString ));
        i = j;      

    }
}
return sb.toString(); //Or whatever you do with it.
```

Comment: Man thanks a lot, it increase a lot the decoding process thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Using substring for different lengths of strings would really slow things down.  In Java 7 it takes a copy of the original string creating two objects.  You are much better off creating one substring and doing a search against a NavigableMap.

Using a NavigableMap will allow you to find the longest matching string in one operation and reduce the number of strings you need to store in the map.

Note: even so the size of the Map will be O(N^2) where N is the maximum string length you can look back, so you have to place a sensible limit on the size of N.

Note2: You will be lucky to get within a tenth of the speed of the built in huffman code (which is written for you, is standard and works) So if performance matters, use that.